Why are the transform buttons greyed out in the static mesh editor?
I am trying to add a couple box colliders to my mesh. I'd like to scale and position them. But for whatever reason, my transform buttons are greyed out and I don't know why. It's like this whenever I try to edit any mesh.
I'm just trying to follow the tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVBPUVI8Dc0


I needed to click the box collider first
